# How concatenation and shifting the bits can be implemented in c?

Tags: c, type-conversion, bit-manipulation

I want to left sift by 1 bit and concatenate bits to `uint8_t` *pointer* i,e.:

```
for (i = 0; i < hex_len; i++)
    hex[i] = (hex[i] << 1);  //left sift of 1 bit
 hex[0] = hex[0] & 0x01;    // write 0x01 in the Least significant bit.
```

Any help regrading this will be appriciated...

Comment: _i want the following pseudocode to implement:_ - Make your dream come true...

Comment: _hex_ variable should be twice as large as _str_ variable - try to input more than 50 characters into _str_ variable and you will notice buffer overflow at _hex_

Comment: `hex[j] = '\0';` is not needed here as you are setting while buffer to values of '0' with `memset(...)` function

Comment: the hex is of type uint8_t, therefore it can store 8 bit

Comment: Please submit smallest complete program we can verify, point out where you stuck and we may help you. _i want the following pseudocode to implement:_ is not something you would like to ask SO

Comment: `sizeof(hex)` is not doing what you expect. Try to add this in the function: `printf("%zu \n", sizeof(hex));`

Comment: It's unclear to me what you want to do. **If** you could do this bit shift then codelike `hex=(hex<<1)&0x01;` would result in zero. Can you explain it a bit more?

Comment: i want <<1 bit to the value  0x7374616B656F766572666C6F77

Comment: `hex[0]=hex[0]&0x01;    // write 0x01 in the Least significant bit.` does not write 1 to the lsb, that would be `hex[0] |= 1;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got desired result by implementing my program in follwing way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

uint8_t *fun_string2hex(char *str,uint8_t *hex){

  int i=0,j=0;
  memset(hex,0,sizeof(hex));
   /*converting str character into Hex and adding into strH*/
    for(i=0,j=0;i<strlen(str);i++,j+=2)
    { 
        sprintf((char*)hex+j,"%02X",str[i]);
    }
    hex[j]='\0';
    return hex;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  if(argc<2){
     printf("Usage: %s <Input_string>\n", argv[0]);
        return -1;
  }
     int i=0;
     int count1=0,count2=0;
     uint8_t str_len=0x0;
     str_len=strlen(argv[1]);

     unsigned char str[str_len];
     uint8_t hex[str_len*2];
     uint8_t hex_org[str_len];
     uint8_t convert1_char2hex=0x0,convert2_char2hex=0x0,hex_concatination=0x0;
     for(i=0;i<str_len;i++){
       str[i]=argv[1][i];
     }
     str[i]='\0';
     fun_string2hex(str,hex);

     for(i=0;i<str_len;i++){
    count2=(2*((i+1)-1))+1;
    count1=2*((i+1)-1);
    convert1_char2hex=hex[count1];
    convert1_char2hex=(strtol(&convert1_char2hex, NULL, 16)<<4);
    convert2_char2hex=hex[count2];
    convert2_char2hex=strtol(&convert2_char2hex, NULL, 16);
    hex_concatination=((convert1_char2hex)|(convert2_char2hex));
    hex_org[i]=hex_concatination;
     }
     for(int i=0;i<str_len;i++)
    printf("%0x",hex_org[i]);
     printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In C there is no operator that can do left bit shift on a whole array.

So you'll have to implement a function that can do it. This can be done by shifting the individual elements of the array while handling a carry from the next element into the current element.

Something like the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

void shift_uint8_array_left(uint8_t *hex, size_t size)
{
    size_t i; 
    if (size == 0) return;
    for(i=0; i < size-1; i++) 
    {
        size_t carry = (hex[i+1] & 0x80) ? 1 : 0; // Calculate carry
        hex[i] = hex[i] << 1;                     // Shift current element
        hex[i] = hex[i] | carry;                  // Add the carry
    }
    hex[i] = hex[i] << 1;                         // Last element never has a carry
}

#define NUM_UINT8_to_SHIFT 3

int main(void) 
{
    uint8_t hex[100] = {0x1, 0x81, 0x4};

    for (size_t i=0; i<NUM_UINT8_to_SHIFT; ++i) printf("%02X", hex[i]);
    printf("\n");

    shift_uint8_array_left(hex, NUM_UINT8_to_SHIFT);

    for (size_t i=0; i<NUM_UINT8_to_SHIFT; ++i) printf("%02X", hex[i]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
018104
030208
```

Comment: `shift_uint8_array_left` should test if `size > 0`. As coded, the behavior is catastrophic

Comment: I would also remove the `100` size specifier and size `sizeof(hex)` instead of hardcoding a count of `3`.

Comment: @chqrlie Fully agree with the `size > 0` check - answer updated. With respect to the 100 and the 3 I think OP use case is that the array is larger than the actual number of elements containing valid data. Hence there is a difference in `sizeof(hex)` and the number of elements to shift. BTW - the important part of the code is in `shift_uint8_array_left` while the code in `main` is just to illustrate how the function is called and what the result was.